# UIlabel data is not aligned?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I'll show you my problem by image. I have tableView in which i customize the UITableViewCell and tableViewCell having UILabel field. In this UILabel field data is coming by parsing the XML file data come completely but a little alignment problem it looks like a paragraph showing in image given below:-

[image]

and this in my code which is used to print data on this UItableViewCell's UILabel:-

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableCell13" owner:self options:NULL];
        cell = nibLoadedCell;
    }
    titleLabel.text = aNewsInfo.title;
    return cell; }
```

and I used Interface Builder (IB) for designing the cell i showing the setting by the image given blow for the UITableView cells UILabel :-

[image]

any one suggest me the method how can i rectify this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, Change the line break mode and then try.

Comment: Uncooperative "blow lines" can be quite frustrating. I commiserate. (see 1st pic if you're wondering WTF :-))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the UILabel display the indentation when you set the text via IB? If not, I suspect that your parsed text has a space at the beginning. Try using:

```
titleLabel.text = [aNewsInfo.title stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

And if that works, put this in your parser for all strings found for each tag.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one or two space coming from your server xml file. Did you check string you are getting from xml have spaces or not ?